# How to describe the entanglement in the jets?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-entanglement

Consider a pair of quark and anti quark flew away and generate the "jets"(whatever that meant).
But from the color conservation, it was assured that the seemly isolated jets that was generated by the quark and anti quark would have at least one intersection, and thus at least one "loop" must appear in the Feynman diagram. In the plain term, the quark and anti quark pair and the jets generated was entangled states and could not be treated as independent.

That's the language of the quantum mechanics. However, in the more sophisticated language of QFT,(taking QFT II) rarely did one encounter the concept of the entanglement. In canonical quantization the commutation operator were local, the states were vacuum, and the wave functions were plain waves. In the path integral,(perturbative) it was the propagators and the actions.

It's clear that there's a big leap between the usual language of the QFT and the entanglement of the jets.
Was there a way to understand it without too much complication?
How to describe the entanglement in the jets?

Comment: [Jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(particle_physics)) are sprays of  (color neutral) hadrons summarizing zillions of soft interactions dressing up fast quarks into hadrons. Entanglement normally indicates QM interference, so a property of loop diagrams in the core process, but for tree diagrams you just have helicity, kinematic, flavor, etc... correlations only. QM angular momentum features are crudely apparent. What is your question?

Comment: @CosmasZachos That might be usually how it was explained to the students but it simply could not be true, because it was not about a zillions number of events but that there's a the probability of $1$of a loop formation in the subsequent tree diagram that must happen. The interesting thing was 1. how to describe the entanglement(the question) 2. if you really thought about it this was a very strong constrain, because for those random particles to be produced into (almost)arbitrary direction in space time with (almost) arbitrary momentum, at some spacetime two of the particles must intersect.

Comment: I don't recognize mainstream hard QCD embedded into the parton model in what you are saying, and I'm not sure what you mean by "entanglement": It is a charged word applied to very different phenomena. Here, it is a placeholder for "QM interference" and a single tree diagram lacks it.

Comment: Is [this](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.ns.42.120192.000453) what you are asking about?